# Unable to visit dynamic route on Next.js only in production

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am on a Next.js project and my team and I are having an issue when I try to dynamically render a page. This only happens on production when I deploy the project on the Google Cloud Platform.

My folder structure is the following:

```
pages
   users
      [userId].js
   index.js
```

The issue happens when I try to visit the [userId].js route from index.js

Both pages are making use of `getServerSideProps()`

`index.js`:

```
export const getServerSideProps =  async(context)=>{ 
  const client = buildClient(context);
  const { data } = await client.get("/api/residents");
  return { props:{residents: data} };
}

const LandingPage = ({ currentUser, users }) => {

  const { addProduct, cartItems, increase } = useContext(CartContext);

  const usersList = users.map((user) => {

    return (
      <tr key={resident.id}>
        <td className={styles.tableCell}>{user.user.name}</td>
        <td className={styles.tableCell}>{user.neighborhood}</td>
        <td className={styles.tableCell}>
          {user.neighborhoodDescription}
        </td>
        <td className={styles.tableCell}>
          <Link href= "/users/[userId]" as={`/users/${user.id}`} > { // <<-----
            View
          </Link>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
  return (
     ....
  );
};
```

`[userId].js`

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context ) {
  // Fetch necessary data for the blog post using params.id
  const {residentId} = context.query;
  const userData = await getResidentData(residentId, context);

  return {
    props: {
      resident:userData.data || null,
      products: []
    },
  };
}

const ResidentShow = ({currentUser, resident, products}) => {       
    …
}
```

why am I not able to render [userId].js when I try to visit that page from index.js. This only happens when I deploy on the Google Cloud. Locally, the project runs smoothly.